# Why do I get unexpected values when I access an object stored in a list-view item?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

When I use a record in a thread, e.g.:

```
type

TClient = Class(TThread)
public
    mcmd:record
    cid:Byte;
    kd, recvresponse:Boolean;
end;
```

when I try to access a variable it returns a random value.
Is it a problem with the compiler?
I'm using Delphi 6 on Windows 7 x64 & what I do to access it is:

```
var
    c:TClient;
begin
    if listview1.itemfocused = nil then Exit;
    c := ListView1.ItemFocused.Data;
    if c = nil then Exit;
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(c.mcid.cid));
end;
```

how I assign the itemfocused data variable is by doing:

```
Procedure TClient.New;
Begin
    Main.ListView1.Items.BeginUpdate;
    item := Main.ListView1.Items.Add;
    item.Caption := Split(dat1, '|', 0);
    item.SubItems.Add(ip);
    item.Data := @Self;
    Main.ListView1.Items.EndUpdate;
End;
```

which I call by `Synchronize`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. That is not complete, valid code (it's missing at least one `end;`), and you've provided no code that shows how you're "accessing a variable" that we can use to identify the problem. Please [edit] your question to provide actual, compilable code that demonstrates the problem, and then show the code that's causing the problem you're having. Accessing a record inside a thread is not a problem when the record is a member (field) of the thread class. Please see [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for more information on posting a code sample we can use.

Comment: I added some more code, sorry for not providing enough.

Comment: You're showing no code that creates the thread. Where does that happen? (There are many other things wrong with your code, but that's a different topic.) The definition of `TClient` you posted contains no method `New`. Once again, [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: How did you conclude that records were relevant to your problem? Did your code work when your fields weren't records? I doubt it. Don't jump to unfounded conclusions.

Comment: I thought it was records as I did not do any extra testing, and assumed it was the record that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Self` is a local variable. The pointer you store in `Data` becomes invalid as soon as `New` returns. Instead of storing a pointer to `Self`, you need to store its value:

```
Item.Data := Self;
```

If that doesn't compile, type-cast.

Comment: that was so stupid of me lol, I thought that to reference the object you needed to create a pointer to it by @object...Thanks! :)